# Access Database not inserting records

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Solved: i just managed to solve the problem  by creating a new table and removing [IT-DEC], [IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME], [IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME] where i replaced them by strings accepted by access such as ITDECMAKER  ITDECMAKEFNAME  ITDECMAKERLNAME

Looks like the problem is solved, however if anyone has a theory to why this has happened id really appreciate your contribution

thank you

I am facing trouble with inserting more than one line of data into my table. For example i load my form and input the data into textbox all information are inserted into their respective tables accordingly, however for the second time when i want to insert data, all data are inserted succesffuly in their respective tables except for one table which is not taking any more data thus only allowing for one line of data.

This is the code i am using in the same form

This part of code is responsible for the userinfo table which is not accepting more than one record

```
Private Sub proceedBTN_Click()

GlobalVar.flp = Me.qfirstname + Me.qlastname + Me.qmobile

 CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserInfo(" _
 & "FLP, FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTitle, PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " _
 & "[IT-DEC], [IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME], [IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME], Contact, ContactMethodPhone, " _
 & "ContactMethodEmail, ContactMethodFax, ContactMethodPostal ,    AcquisitionTimeFrame,        Budget  ) " _
   & "VALUES('" & GlobalVar.flp & "','" & Me.qfirstname & "','" & Me.qlastname & "','" &     Me.qcompany & "','" & Me.qjob & "','" & Me.qphone & "','" & Me.qmobile & "','" &    Me.qemail & "','" _
   & Me.qfax & "','" & Me.itdecopt & "','" & Me.qitfirstname & "','" & Me.qitlastname &   "','" & Me.contactoption & "','" _
   & Me.contactphoneopt & "','" & Me.contactemailopt & "','" & Me.contactfaxopt & "','" &     Me.contactpostalopt & "','" & Me.acquisitionoption & "','" & Me.budgetoption & "');"
```

This Code is responsible for inserting into the UserPartners table which allows succesffuly entering multiple records.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserPartners(" _
 & "FLP, PartnerACT, PartnerBMB, PartnerEverTeam, " _
 & "PartnerFormatech, PartnerICC, PartnerIBS, PartnerMegaTek, PartnerMDS,     PartnerProcomix, PartnerSetsSolutions, " _
 & "PartnerTripleC, PartnerNewHorizons, PartnerPromethean, PartnerTeletrade,     PartnerNokia, PartnerPolycom, PartnerDell ) " _
     & "VALUES('" & GlobalVar.flp & "','" & Me.partneract & "','" & Me.partnerbmb & "','" _
     & Me.partnereverteam & "','" & Me.partnerformatech & "','" & Me.partnericc & "','" & Me.partneribs & "','" & Me.partnermegatek & "','" & Me.partnermds & "','" _
     & Me.partnerprocomix & "','" & Me.partnersetssolutions & "','" & Me.partnertriplec & "','" & Me.partnernewhorizons & "','" & Me.partnerpromethean & "','" _
     & Me.partnerteletrade & "','" & Me.partnernokia & "','" & Me.partnerpolycom & "','" & Me.partnerdell & "');"
```

Finally this is the code for the whole form

```
Option Compare Database




Private Sub contactoption_Click()

If Me.contactoption.Value = 2 Then
Me.contactemailopt.Enabled = False
Me.contactfaxopt.Enabled = False
Me.contactphoneopt.Enabled = False
Me.contactpostalopt.Enabled = False
Me.partneract.Enabled = False
Me.partnerbmb.Enabled = False
Me.partnerdell.Enabled = False
Me.partneredm.Enabled = False
Me.partnereverteam.Enabled = False
Me.partnerformatech.Enabled = False
Me.partneribs.Enabled = False
Me.partnericc.Enabled = False
Me.partnermds.Enabled = False
Me.partnermegatek.Enabled = False
Me.partnernewhorizons.Enabled = False
Me.partnernokia.Enabled = False
Me.partnerpolycom.Enabled = False
Me.partnerprocomix.Enabled = False
Me.partnerpromethean.Enabled = False
Me.partnersetssolutions.Enabled = False
Me.partnerteletrade.Enabled = False
Me.partnertriplec.Enabled = False
Else: Me.contactemailopt.Enabled = True
Me.contactfaxopt.Enabled = True
Me.contactphoneopt.Enabled = True
Me.contactpostalopt.Enabled = True
Me.partneract.Enabled = True
Me.partnerbmb.Enabled = True
Me.partnerdell.Enabled = True
Me.partneredm.Enabled = True
Me.partnereverteam.Enabled = True
Me.partnerformatech.Enabled = True
Me.partneribs.Enabled = True
Me.partnericc.Enabled = True
Me.partnermds.Enabled = True
Me.partnermegatek.Enabled = True
Me.partnernewhorizons.Enabled = True
Me.partnernokia.Enabled = True
Me.partnerpolycom.Enabled = True
Me.partnerprocomix.Enabled = True
Me.partnerpromethean.Enabled = True
Me.partnersetssolutions.Enabled = True
Me.partnerteletrade.Enabled = True
Me.partnertriplec.Enabled = True

End If

End Sub

Private Sub itdecopt_Click()

If Me.itdecopt.Value = 1 Then
Me.qitfirstname.Enabled = False
Me.qitlastname.Enabled = False
Else: Me.qitfirstname.Enabled = True
Me.qitlastname.Enabled = True

End If

End Sub



Private Sub proceedBTN_Click()

GlobalVar.flp = Me.qfirstname + Me.qlastname + Me.qmobile

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserInfo(" _
& "FLP, FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTitle, PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " _
& "[IT-DEC], [IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME], [IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME], Contact, ContactMethodPhone,     " _
& "ContactMethodEmail, ContactMethodFax, ContactMethodPostal , AcquisitionTimeFrame,     Budget  ) " _
& "VALUES('" & GlobalVar.flp & "','" & Me.qfirstname & "','" & Me.qlastname & "','" & Me.qcompany & "','" & Me.qjob & "','" & Me.qphone & "','" & Me.qmobile & "','" & Me.qemail & "','" _
    & Me.qfax & "','" & Me.itdecopt & "','" & Me.qitfirstname & "','" & Me.qitlastname     & "','" & Me.contactoption & "','" _
& Me.contactphoneopt & "','" & Me.contactemailopt & "','" & Me.contactfaxopt & "','" & Me.contactpostalopt & "','" & Me.acquisitionoption & "','" & Me.budgetoption & "');"


 CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserPartners(" _
 & "FLP, PartnerACT, PartnerBMB, PartnerEverTeam, " _
 & "PartnerFormatech, PartnerICC, PartnerIBS, PartnerMegaTek, PartnerMDS, PartnerProcomix, PartnerSetsSolutions, " _
 & "PartnerTripleC, PartnerNewHorizons, PartnerPromethean, PartnerTeletrade, PartnerNokia, PartnerPolycom, PartnerDell ) " _
 & "VALUES('" & GlobalVar.flp & "','" & Me.partneract & "','" & Me.partnerbmb & "','" _
 & Me.partnereverteam & "','" & Me.partnerformatech & "','" & Me.partnericc & "','" & Me.partneribs & "','" & Me.partnermegatek & "','" & Me.partnermds & "','" _
 & Me.partnerprocomix & "','" & Me.partnersetssolutions & "','" & Me.partnertriplec & "','" & Me.partnernewhorizons & "','" & Me.partnerpromethean & "','" _
 & Me.partnerteletrade & "','" & Me.partnernokia & "','" & Me.partnerpolycom & "','" & Me.partnerdell & "');"


 CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO UserProducts(" _
 & "FLP, ProductsExchange,ProductsLyncServer, ProductsLync , ProductsOffice, ProductsSharePoint, ProductsSharePointInternet, ProductsWindowsServer, " _
 & "ProductsSystemCenter, ProductsSQL, ProductsWindows7 ) " _
 & "VALUES('" & GlobalVar.flp & "','" & Me.productexchange & "','" & Me.productlyncserver & "','" _
 & Me.productlync & "','" & Me.productoffice & "','" & Me.productsharepoint & "','" & Me.productsharepointinternet & "','" & Me.productserver & "','" & Me.productsystemcenter & "','" _
 & Me.productsql & "','" & Me.productwindows & "');"

DoCmd.OpenForm "DayChoose", acNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, "UserInfo", acSaveYes



End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "one line of data", do you mean one ROW or a data field within the row is only accepting one line? Many problems like this are eliminated by using the Parameters collection and you would be wise to adopt this habit.

Comment: one ROW, for example my table takes firstname lastname job 

lets say i want to insert  john jacob developer
and i want to insert  james rachel philosopher

it will only insert the first one jon jacob developer and anything i try to insert after that wont get inserted into the table and no error would occur, however both will be inserted in other tables successfully

Comment: Use the Tag property of the controls to set a contactoption value, then iterate through the controls checking the tag property and set enabled based on that. It will make your code easier to maintain and more readable.

Comment: What version of MS-Access are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I can help you, please rework using parameters as follows:

```
Private Sub proceedBTN_Click()
    Dim Db As DAO.Database
    Set Db = CurrentDb
    Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "INSERT INTO UserInfo(" & _
      "FLP, FirstName, LastName, Company, JobTitle, PhoneNumber, Mobile, Email, Fax, " & _
      "[IT-DEC], [IT-DEC-MAKER-FNAME], [IT-DEC-MAKER-LNAME], Contact, ContactMethodPhone, " & _
      "ContactMethodEmail, ContactMethodFax, ContactMethodPostal ,    AcquisitionTimeFrame, Budget) " & _
      "VALUES([pflp], [pfirstname], [pqlastname], [pqcompany],[pqjob],[pqphone],[pqmobile], [pqemail]," & _
            "[pqfax],[pitdecopt],pqitfirstname,[pqitlastname],[pcontactoption],[pcontactphoneopt],[pcontactemailopt]," & _
            "[pcontactfaxopt],[pcontactpostalopt],[pacquisitionoption],[pbudgetoption]);"

    Set qd = Db.CreateQueryDef("", SQL)
    qd.Parameters("pflp") = GlobalVar.flp
    qd.Parameters("pfirstname") = Me.qfirstname
    ' continue filling parameters....
    qd.Parameters("pbudgetoption").Value = Me.budgetoption
    qd.Execute

End Sub
```

If this does not resolve your issue, we can dig a little deeper.